# What's the meaning of \'$char in bash?

Tags: python, bash, printf

I'm debugging some code in bash and trying to implement it in python. However I cannot understand the following piece of code:

```sh
echo "CBCC<FCEEFFGGG99@,9CF9EF9" \
| grep -o . \
| while read char; do 
     printf "%d\n" \'$char; 
  done
```

This gives the following ouput:

```
 67 66 67 67 60 70 67 69 69 70 70 71 71 71 57 57 64 44 57 67 70 57 69 70 57
```

The part which I cannot find information is in the **printf** statement. 
What `\'$char` stands for, and why it is used? How can I translate into python?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: 'X (a literal single-quote infront of a character): interpreted as number (underlying codeset) don't forget escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'X
```

for printf will interpret X as number

```
\'X
```

backslash is escape char otherwise you'll need to close quotes

```
ord(X)
```

should do the trick in python

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and also for the python trick, it worked!

Comment: @mrDanSoro, since this answer solved your problem you should "accept" it by clicking on the big checkmark on its left. (You can also upvote all answers you found helpful: Click on the up arrow above the current vote total.)

Answer (score 1):

The backslash escapes the single quote from the shell (otherwise it would start a quoted string). The net effect is that a literal single quote is pasted in front of the value of the variable `char`.

Comment: OK, so the end result in this case is the same as `"'$char"`. Why does this lead to the output the OP has shown though?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @TomFenech Do you know? I've just tried searching for it but there only seems to be examples but no actual documentation on why it converts it to decimal.

Comment: @TomFenech Found it `If the leading character is a single-quote or double-quote, the value shall be the numeric value in the underlying codeset of the character following the single-quote or double-quote.` [Here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html)

Comment: I'd say that comment is the most useful answer on the page!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you print the decimal value of the Ascii code for each character in the mentioned string.

so \'$char will take characters in the string

```
CBCC<FCEEFFGGG99@,9CF9EF9
```

and substitute each character to print its decimal value.